# How do you add a compound / composite index on a PostgreSQL table with TimescaleDB installed?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb

How do you add a compound / composite index on a PostgreSQL table with TimescaleDB installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/schema-management, you can add a compound / composite index to TimescaleDB by simply doing:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON conditions (time DESC, cityid)
WHERE cityid IS NOT NULL;
```

`time` is a column with timestamps (The one used as primary key in TimescaleDB).
`cityid` is a column for a city identifier we might to often query for (As second parameter after the time series dates).

This can be done before or after converting the table to a hypertable.

To avoid bloating the index when the column `cityid` is often `NULL`, the statement `WHERE cityid IS NOT NULL` is for. Use this per default unless you are often searching for missing data (`cityid IS NULL`).

Comment: (Timescale person here).   @FranzHuber23's answer is correct -- you can create an index in TimescaleDB just like it's a standard PG table.

For more "best practices" around composite index creation, you might also find this blog post helpful:   https://blog.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/